# Json Schema validation not working for Draft 7 required properties in nested object depending on a value

Tags: java, json-schema-validator

Request JSON:

```
 {
        "apiVersion":"0.0.9b",
        "apiDate":"18.01.19",
    
        "general":{
            "documentType": "invoice",
    },
            "references":{
    
                "invoiceId":"123",
                "invoiceDate":"01.01.1970",
    
                "creditNoteId":"123",
                "creditNoteDate":"01.01.1970"
            }
        
    }
```

I have to validate request json based on documentType value if documentType is invoice then invoiceId and invoiceDate required if documentType  is creditNote then creditNoteId and creditNoteDate required.

I tried the below schema but it is not working as expected
Updated JSON Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "apiVersion",
    "apiDate"
  ],

  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "general": {
          "properties": {
            "documentType": {
              "enum": [
                "invoice"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
          "references": {
            "required": [
              "invoiceId",
              "invoiceDate"
            ]
          }

      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "general": {
          "properties": {
            "documentType": {
              "enum": [
                "creditNote"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "references": {
          "required": [
            "creditNoteId",
            "creditNoteDate"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "apiVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The version of the json file"
    },
    "apiDate": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The date when the json version was published"
    },
    "general": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/general_identifiers"
    },
      "references": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "invoiceId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "invoiceDate": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "creditNoteId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "creditNoteDate": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }

  },
  "definitions": {
    "general_identifiers": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "documentType"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "documentType": {
          "enum": [
            "invoice",
            "creditNote"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

No validation Error even if m not setting any of required field.
What have I missed?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The validator response is correct. Your schema requires the "references" property to be **under** the "general" node.
But this is not the case in your sample json (it is on the same level, not as child)

```
"general":{
        "documentType": "invoice",
  },
"references":{
...}
```

Comment: Thank you @TacheDeChoco for the explanation. here reference json object is not a child of general both are independent object but i have to validate reference json fields  based on documentType  so how can i achieve ??

Comment: some piece of code i updated and now its not giving any validation error :(                                                                           "properties": {
        "general": {
          "properties": {
            "documentType": {
              "enum": [
                "creditNote"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "references": {
          "required": [
            "creditNoteId",
            "creditNoteDate"
          ]
        }
      }